# AsyncFileUploader in side Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am using AJAX AsyncFileUploader inside a update Panel.
But it is not working.
Can any body help me with some alternate method.

Thanks

Comment: can you post some code from which I can understand the code and give you answer.

Comment: <ContentTemplate>                            <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="UploadResume" runat="server" UploaderStyle="Modern" align = "left" Visible = "false"/>
</ContentTemplate>

Comment: it seems your code will hide the FIleUpload Control. you have set the visible="false".

Comment: Thnax for your reply.
But it is showing the Control. But not working

Comment: @SantoshSahu: AJAX AsyncFileUploader itself used for asynchronous file upload, then why are you using it inside a update panel ??

Answer (score 0):

you have to set these events of your File Control.

```
OnClientUploadError="uploadError" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define the client upload events and optionally set the OnUploadedComplete server-side event:

```
<ajax:AsyncFileUpload ID="UploadResume" runat="server" Width="450px"
OnClientUploadError="UploadError"
OnClientUploadComplete="UploadComplete" 
OnUploadedComplete="OnUploadComplete"
UploaderStyle="Modern" 
UploadingBackColor="#CCFFFF"/>
```

**Client-side event handlers (JavaScript)**

```
function UploadError(sender, args) 
{
    var e = args.get_errorMessage();
    var fn = args.get_fileName();
}
function UploadComplete(sender, args) 
{
    var content_type = args.get_contentType();
    var size = args.get_length()/1000 + " Kbytes";
}
```

**Server-side event handler (C#)**

```
protected void OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    if (UploadResume.HasFile)
    {
        // do something with uploaded file, e.g. save
        String path = MapPath("yourpath") + Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
        UploadResume.SaveAs(path);
    }
    else
    {
        // error
    }
}
```

You don't *need* to use an UpdatePanel for this example, but it will work when inside one.

Answer (score 0):

For those that may be struggling I had a similar update panel issue. Even when I added AsyncFileUpload1 as a postback trigger for the update panel, it still would not work.

I ended up adding an extra, completely unused, AsyncFileUpload3 on the main page outside the update panel, which causes the AsyncFileUpload1 within the update panel to work correctly. I have no idea why this works aside from they must be sharing resources.

The unused AsyncFileUpload3 must be visible for this to work, so I set it to disabled, with a width of 0%. If anybody has insight as to why this works I'd be more than curious. I am coding in VB